# Wpf calendar show many months

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i need to show at least two months (secuential) at the same time in the same calendar but can't find to do this with the calentdar control of WPF.

How can I Do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add two calendars and two way bind the displaydate of the second to the displaydate of the first using the following converter and 1 as the ConverterParameter)

```
Public Class AddMonthConverter
    Implements Windows.Data.IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Return addMonths(value, targetType, parameter, True)
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Return addMonths(value, targetType, parameter, False)
    End Function

    Private Function addMonths(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal isIncrease As Boolean) As Object
        If Not (targetType Is GetType(DateTime?) OrElse targetType Is GetType(DateTime)) Then 
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("The target and value must be a DateTime?")
        Else
            Dim dteValue As DateTime? = CType(value, DateTime?)
            Dim intMonthsToAdd As Int32

            If parameter Is Nothing OrElse Int32.TryParse(parameter.ToString, intMonthsToAdd) = False Then
                intMonthsToAdd = -1
            End If

            If dteValue.HasValue Then
                If isIncrease Then
                    Return dteValue.Value.AddMonths(intMonthsToAdd)
                Else
                    Return dteValue.Value.AddMonths(-intMonthsToAdd)
                End If

            Else
                Return dteValue
            End If

        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: That's the beauty of stackoverflow, Very tks I'm Going to try it.... but must traslate to C# sintax first.